# No match for Java Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I am running into an issue where my code is unable to find regex occurrences. Code:

```
String content = "This\ is\ an\ example.=This is an example\nThis\ is\ second\:=This is second"
String regex = "\"^.*(?=\\=)\"gm";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);
List<String> mKeys = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
   mKeys.add(m.group());
}
```

mKeys turns out to be empty. I have already validated my regex here https://regex101.com/r/YResRc/3. I am expecting the list to contain two keys from the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content contains no `"` quotes, and no text `gm`, so why would you expect that regex to match?

*FYI:* Syntaxes like `"foo"gm` or `/foo/gm` are something other languages do for regex literals. Java doesn't do that.

The `g` flag is implied by the fact that you're using a `find()` loop, and `m` is the [`MULTILINE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE) flag that affects `^` and `$` and you can specify that using the `(?m)` pattern, or by adding a second parameter to [`compile()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#compile-java.lang.String-int-), i.e. one of these ways:

```java
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("foo", Pattern.MULTILINE);

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?m)foo");
```

Your regex should simply be:

```regex
(?m)^.*(?==)
```

which means: Match everything from the beginning of a line up to the last `=` sign on the line.

*Test*

```java
String content = "This is an example.=This is an example\nThis is second:=This is second";
String regex = "(?m)^.*(?==)";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(content);
List<String> mKeys = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
   mKeys.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(mKeys);
```

*Output*

```
[This is an example., This is second:]
```